# Can't convert from Task<internface> to Task<IEnumerable<Interface>>

Tags: c#, moq

This should be a simple question but it's stumping me. I am trying to setup a mock test and have a problem with the return type.

```
private IClassService classService;
var mockClassService = new Mock<IClassService>();
mockClassService.Setup(c => c.GetClasses(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(() => { return Task.FromResult<IClassInfo>(new ClassInfo()); });
classService = mockClassService.Object;
```

I am getting the error "cannot convert from Task<`IClassInfo`> to Task<`IEnumerable<IClassInfo`>>"

I know i have to return a new list of IClassInfo but can't seem to wrap my head around how. Can someone give me some direction?

Comment: `new[] { new ClassInfo()}` would work as an `IEnumerable<IClassInfo>`

Comment: Could also use `ReturnsAsync` instead so the `Task.FromResult` isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `return` to

```
return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<IClassInfo>>(new[] {new ClassInfo()});
```

if you want one `ClassInfo` in the results or

```
return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<IClassInfo>>(Enumerable.Empty<IClassInfo>());
```

for an empty collection.  You could even put `null` in there depending on what your test calls for, the really important part is getting the correct type for `FromResult`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for. I don't know how I missed this.